# How to render boolean data attributes with Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, haml

**UPDATE:** Haml, indeed, already does this automatically! However, I had a hash inside of `link_to` helper, not a Haml tag and didn't even notice it. Silly me! So the question is pretty much invalid.

Haml makes rendering boolean HTML attributes very easy:

```
%input{checked: @boolean}
```

renders a simple `<input>` if `@boolean` is falsy, or `<input checked>` otherwise.

Haml also makes it easy to render data attributes:

```
%a{data: { is_special: false } }
```

renders: `<a data-is-special="false">`.

Is there any way to ask Haml to interpret this custom `data-is-special` attribute as a boolean one? I would like to **not** have it present if a falsy value is assigned, and for it to be present if anything truthy is assigned.

Comment: %input{:checked => true} is the proper haml boolean attribute syntax, as mentioned in the update for anyone interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in brackets is normal ruby code, so if only you could perform this task in ruby, you have yourself a solution. I came up with something like that:

```
def remove_false(hsh)
  Hash[hsh.each_pair.select {|key, value| value}]
end

{data: remove_false(is_special: false)} #=> {:data => {}}
```

This solution does not play well if you have combined keys that you want to treat specially and normally in single hash.

Comment: Nice! I wonder, though, if Haml could do something smart for attributes that begin with `is-` or end with a question mark.

Comment: Oh, Haml already does this exactly the way I asked. It's just that I had a hash inside a Rails helper and not Haml tag. Thanks anyway, this is still useful for helpers.